# how to add parameter into window.open()?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I suppose to use window.open() to create a new window by using the data which I got from mysql.

but I don't know how to put the data into window.open() correctly,

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
include("connMysql.php");
$seldb = @mysql_select_db("database");
if (!$seldb) die("lost connection！");

$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `gp_info` WHERE `type`='hotel' AND `gp_name`='".$_GET["gp_name"]."' order by date ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql_query);?>
```

and I write this

```
<input type="button" value="correspond" onClick="window.open('correspond.php'+'?='+'$GET_[gp_name]','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');"></th>
```

but seems cannot get $GET_[gp_name]?

can someone help??

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: **Unclear** Does the query fail? Does the query work? Where in the PHP are you attempting to generate the `<input>` ?????

Comment: I think you mean $_GET[gp_name]

Comment: `$GET_[gp_name]` WRONG .... `$_GET[gp_name]` Maybe what you want or `$_GET['gp_name']`

Comment: I correct $GET_[gp_name] to $_GET[gp_name], but still doesn't work...

Comment: **Pro tip:** To troubleshoot this kind of thing, first try typing your `window.open` function call into the Javascript console in the dev tools in your browser. When you get it right--when you know exactly the correct form of the function call--then program it into your php code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should try this code

```
<input type="button" value="correspond" onClick="window.open('correspond.php?=<?php echo $GET_["gp_name"] ?>','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');"></th>
```

i hope it will work

Comment: Did you read any of the comments?

Comment: And a description of what you changed AND why you changed it will always make for a better answer that the OP does not have to ask for clarification on